Proving the existence of a functional for a set and a exterior point
I am trying to prove this excercise from my Functional analysis book:

Let $(E, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ a real normed espace, $A \subseteq E$ an open and convex subset such that $0 \in A$ and $x_0 \in E \setminus A$ . Then, there is $f \in E'$ such that $\forall x \in A: f(x) < f(x_0)$ $(*)$.

My idea was to take the Minkowsky functional for $A$, call it $p_A$ . On a set with the propperties of $A$, $p_A$ is bounded and satisfies that $A = \{ x \in E : p_A(x) < 1 \}$, so we would have $(*)$ automatically. The only problem is that, at least on my notes, the Minkowsky functional is not proved to be linear. I mean, what it is prove for it is that $\forall (\lambda, x, y) \in \Bbb{R} \times E \times E : p_A(\lambda x) = |\lambda| p_A(x) \, \land \, p_A(x+y) \leq p_A(x) + p_A(y)$  and I am having problems to see how to prove what it is missing to be a propper linear function, so any possible advice or help would be appreciated.

The Minkowski functional of a convex set is hardly ever linear (for example, because it is positive). Also, the absolut homogeneity $p_A(\lambda x)=|\lambda|p_A(x)$ is not true in general (you would need a symmetric set $A$). However, the standard version of the Hahn-Banach theorem needs a sublinear majorant (although a convex majorant is enough) and applies to you $p_A$.

@Jochen I see, this helps a lot, thanks!
